# Combine 2 dates with one format?

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

Is it possible to define a format that combines 2 dates?
E.g. assume I have `date1` e.g. 15/1/2016 and `date2`.  e.g. 20/1/2016
Is there any format that I could use to show something like:
15-20 Jan 2016 ?

Other example:
E.g. assume I have `date1` e.g. 15/1/2016 and `date2`.  e.g. 20/5/2016
Result: 15 Jan - 20 May 2016

Comment: What would be the type of the resulting object ? a date ? a string ?

Comment: @ortis:I want a string

Comment: What happened to the "January" information in 15/1/2016? Please post the exact rules that you want.

Comment: @Tunaki:Sorry about that. Updated OP

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this. Ofcourse this does not take into account that the dates may be in different months or years. It takes the month and year from `startDate`.

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 5, 15);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 5, 20);

String text = String.format("%1$te-%2$te %1$tB %1$tY", startDate, endDate);

System.out.println(text);
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for how the format string works.

NOTE: This uses Java 8 `java.time.LocalDate` and not Joda Time.

Comment: What about wider date range? Like the second example

Comment: @Jim change the format string, for example to: `"%1$te %1$tb - %2$te %2$tb %1$tY"` - see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (<= click the link).

Answer (score 1):

15-20 May 2016 - this is not a true date format . i dont think that there is any format to do this. but you can define your own method which will return an string
and if you are using java 8 use localDate

```
LocalDate myDate = new LocalDate("2016-5-15");
LocalDate endDate =new LocalDate(2016-5-20);

String format = mydate.getDayOfMonth() 
+"-"+ endDate.getDayOfMonth() 
+" "+endDate.getMonth().toString()
+" "+endDate.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String dateRangeToString(Date date1, Date date2){
    Calendar firstCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    firstCal.setTime(date1);
    Calendar secondCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    secondCal .setTime(date2);
    if (firstCal.getTimeInMillis() > secondCal.getTimeInMillis()){
        firstCal.setTime(date2);
        secondCal .setTime(date1);
    }
    String result;
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
    if (firstCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) < secondCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)){
        result = format.format(firstCal.getTime()) + " - "  + format.format(secondCal.getTime());
    }
    else if (firstCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) < secondCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)){
        SimpleDateFormat formatTemp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM");
        result = formatTemp .format(firstCal.getTime()) + " - "  + format.format(secondCal.getTime());
    }
    else if (firstCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < secondCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)){
        SimpleDateFormat formatTemp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
        result = formatTemp .format(firstCal.getTime()) + " - " + format.format(secondCal.getTime());
    }
    else{//Both dates are equal
        result = format.format(firstCal.getTime());
    }
    return result;
}
```

That should work, not pretty, but since you can have so many variations, it should manage what you want.

To explain, it has to use an if statement to check what parts of the date are not equal, is it just the year, month or day? Depending on what part fails will dictate which string to output. I then use variations of the `SimpleDateFormat` to output the desired string

**EDIT**
Using the following code:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2013,5,29);
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.set(2012,4,30);
    System.out.println(dateRangeToString(calendar.getTime(), calendar2.getTime()));


    calendar.set(2013,5,29);
    calendar2.set(2013,4,30);
    System.out.println(dateRangeToString(calendar.getTime(), calendar2.getTime()));

    calendar.set(2013,5,29);
    calendar2.set(2013,5,30);
    System.out.println(dateRangeToString(calendar.getTime(), calendar2.getTime()));


    calendar.set(2013,5,30);
    calendar2.set(2013,5,30);
    System.out.println(dateRangeToString(calendar.getTime(), calendar2.getTime()));
```

I get the following results:

> 30 May 2012 - 29 June 2013
>
> 30 May - 29 June 2013
>
> 29 - 30 June 2013
>
> 30 June 2013

Answer (score 0):

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines formats for textual representations of various date-time values.

The standard way to represent a span of time is with the pair of dates formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, conjoined by a slash character.

> 2016-01-15/2016-05-20

## `LocalDate`

Using the `LocalDate` class in the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later, with a pair of `LocalDate` objects named `start` and `stop`.

```
String output = start.toString() + "/" + stop.toString();
```